# How can I serve files while using GRPC

Tags: go, grpc

Is there any way how to serve files in Go with GRPC, like in [gin-gonic's variant](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin):

```
router.Static("/static", "/var/www")
```

Comment: How would one request such a static file?

Comment: Something like http://localhost:8080/image/name.webp

Comment: That looks like an HTTP request, not a GRPC request.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do it exactly like that.
But you can use the proto `bytes` type and put the file bytes in that field.

Also (as pointed out in the comments) with large files you should use streaming instead of a unary call. (most GRPC implementation have a limit of 4MB per message).

Proto example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Response {
    bytes fileChunk = 1;
}
message Request {
    string fileName = 1;
}

service TestService {
    rpc Download(Request) returns (stream Response);
}
```

Server implementation example:

```
func (srv *Server) Download(req *pbgo.Request, responseStream pbgo.TestService_DownloadServer) error {
    bufferSize := 64 *1024 //64KiB, tweak this as desired
    file, err := os.Open(req.GetFileName())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    buff := make([]byte, bufferSize)
    for {
        bytesRead, err := file.Read(buff)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            break
        }
        resp := &pbgo.Response{
            FileChunk: buff[:bytesRead],
        }
        err = responseStream.Send(resp)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error while sending chunk:", err)
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Client would call it like this:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9090", grpc.WithInsecure())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("client could connect to grpc service:", err)
}
c := pbgo.NewTestServiceClient(conn)
fileStreamResponse, err := c.Download(context.TODO(), &pbgo.Request{
    FileName: "test.txt",
})
if err != nil {
    log.Println("error downloading:", err)
    return
}
for {
    chunkResponse, err := fileStreamResponse.Recv()
    if err == io.EOF {
        log.Println("received all chunks")
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("err receiving chunk:", err)
        break
    }
    log.Printf("got new chunk with data: %s \n", chunkResponse.FileChunk)
}
```

If you need to be able to serve arbitrary files, you would need to handle which files you allow serving (say someone requests the file `/etc/passwd` or something).
Not sure what exactly is the use case here.

Comment: There is a default size limit for gRPC messages (4MB?). So any large files cannot be served like this without chunking.

Comment: Didn't realize that, thanks. So a streaming rpc call would be needed then. I'll try that out and update the post.

Comment: Yes, I streaming gRPC would be ideal in this case. Each message could hold chunk info e.g. "chunk 3 of 8" and byte range, so the client can prepare on how to receive the file e.g. seek-writes etc.

Comment: @erikbozic How to handle the client side if it is react-js and if it uses http mapping/annotations for grpc endpoints on server side?

Comment: How to get `pbgo.TestService_DownloadServer` in the pb file?

Comment: @BAE `TestService_DownloadServer` will be in the generated `TestService_Download_grpc.pb.go` file you generate with `protoc` something like `protoc --go-grpc_out=../pkg *.proto` but exact details will vary depending on your service name etc.